# SourceTree can not recognise Manifest files

Tags: git, android-studio, manifest, atlassian-sourcetree

I am having a problem with Github. I am using SourceTree like a tool to manage Android source code from github and Android Studio like tool for development.

In the first time I have added source code to Git, SourceTree could not recognise file Manifest.xml and some other files. I have never met this case before when using Eclipse.

Does someone meet this case before? If you already met it, do you know how to resolve it?

Comment: This could be an issue with your .gitignore configuration.  Can you confirm that your local and global .gitignore files don't exclude those files?

Comment: @BJ Myers: thanks you for your answer. I confirm that! I checked this ignore file and do not see Manifest file inside. I just ignore all files in _bin_ folder. Maybe it does not effect and not a reason for this issue.